# Remove underscore from a list: Python

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have the following list:

```
my_list = ['aaa', 'bb_bb', 'cc', 2]
```

I would like to remove underscore `_` from a list element and would like to get

```
my_list = ['aaa', 'bbbb', 'cc', 2]
```

I tried this

```
my_list= [re.sub('_', '', _) for _ in my_list ]
```

For some reason I am getting an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You have an integer in the list.

Comment: The last element of the list is an `int` and `re.sub()` knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because one of the elements is neither string nor bytes.

Also, you do not need [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all instances of a character in a string, use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead, plus using `_` as a variable name usually means it is ignored.

Try this instead:

```
[v.replace('_', '') if isinstance(v, str) else v for v in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you absolutely must/want to stick to regex:

```
import re
my_list = ['aaa', 'bb_bb', 'cc', 2]
my_list= [re.sub('_', '', value) if isinstance(value, str) else value for value in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

Result:

```
['aaa', 'bbbb', 'cc', 2]
```

Comment: Yes, but it's much slower (and more computationally expensive), timing the `str.replace` method gives 1.42 µs ± 132 ns while the `re.sub` method gives 5.64 µs ± 113 ns.

Comment: @ljmc Yes, I know. Maybe some day it's not underscore anymore, but something more complicated, then regex could be something to consider. I'm just leaving this answer as someone else might need it in the future. I upvoted your answer too as I think it's better for this. :)